# Content of Project Wiki

Tags: project-management, wiki

I've set up a small [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) project.  I feel a bit obligated to use the built-in wiki feature, but I'm unsure of what to use it for.

The project is basically a C++ library for container classes.  I'm currently the only member of my project, but I might get a few friends involved.

So, what should I use the wiki for?  Do I even need to use it at all?

Comment: Documentation? Bug reporting? Pretty sure you don't _have_ to use it.

Comment: @aqua Of course I don't *have* to, but if there's a common usage for it then I'd like to know.

Comment: I'd use it for Documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't feel obligated to use it, but I would use it for documentation.

Another possible use could be for collaboration on feature ideas, though wikis aren't exactly the best tool for that.

Comment: How in-depth should the documentation be?  Should I sacrifice comprehension in favor of ease-of-updating by limiting it to function summaries, or should I do the inverse?

Comment: @max That depends on your needs and limitations of the wiki (e.g. limits on the number of pages).  The goal should be utility.  You may be able to provide both comprehensive information and summary information.  For example, a list of the functions could provide summaries for each function and link to more detailed documentation for each function.  I would also keep in mind to avoid duplication as much as possible, since changes would need to be made in more than one location.  The wiki may allow you to inline a section of one page in another, to help with this.